# How to empty an array while i back to my previous screen in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to show some data (from 1st screen to the 2nd second screen) from an array and it works well for the 1st time. But when I back to my previous screen and select another option then it shows present selected data containing previous data too. So I want to empty my array while I back to my 1st screen. How can i do it?

[image: 1st selection]
[image: 1st result]
[image: 2nd selecton]
[image]

1st-screen code here.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, Dimensions, KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import SearchableDropdown from 'react-native-searchable-dropdown';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';


import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

const itm = require('./data/data.json');

var items = "";

function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {

  const [ itemName, setitemName ] = React.useState('')

  const { id } = route.params;

  var ID = JSON.stringify(id);
  //var Vname = JSON.stringify(name);

  var Logoname = "";
  var abc = "";

  if (ID === 1) {
    items = itm.bus;
    Logoname = require('../img/bus2.jpg');
    abc = 'bus'; 
    
  }

  else if (ID === 2) {
    items = itm.train;
    Logoname = require('../img/back2.jpg');
    abc = 'train'; 
  }

  else {
    items = itm.launch;
    Logoname = require('../img/boatbac.jpg');
    abc = 'launch'; 
  } 

  return (

    <>
      {/* <ImageBackground source={Logoname}

        style={styles.backimg}
      > */}

      <LinearGradient start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} colors={['#3E7FF5', '#56BEDA', '#6BF4C2']} style={styles.linearGradient}>

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { Keyboard.dismiss() }}>

        <View style={styles.home}> 
            

            <View style={styles.conatiner} >
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position' >
            <Text style={styles.cardText}>FROM KHULNA TO</Text>

              
              <SearchableDropdown
                onTextChange={text => console.log('')}
               //onItemSelect={item => alert((item.name + " is selected"))}
                onItemSelect={item => setitemName((item.name))}

                containerStyle={{ padding: 0, marginBottom: 20, }}
                textInputStyle={{
                  padding: 8,
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  // backgroundColor: '#14FFFF',

                  borderColor: '#000',
                  borderRadius: 50,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  paddingLeft: 20,
                }}
                itemStyle={{
                  padding: 10,
                  //backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  borderBottomColor: 'red',
                  borderBottomWidth: 1,
                  borderBottomColor: '#000',
                  borderRadius: 5,
                  marginLeft: 5,
                  marginRight: 5,
                }}
                itemTextStyle={{ color: '#222', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '400', }}
                itemsContainerStyle={{ maxHeight: 140 }}
                items={items}
                defaultIndex={null}
                placeholder="Search Here"
                placeholderTextColor="#EDE7F6"
                resetValue={false}

                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              />
              

              <View style={styles.btn}>
                <Button
                  //type="outline"
                  title='SUBMIT'
                  buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#14FFFF', borderRadius: 50,  }}
                  titleStyle={{ color: '#065555', fontSize: 20 }}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Information', {id: ID, name: itemName, SelectType: abc})} />
              </View> 
              </KeyboardAvoidingView>

            </View>

          </View>

        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>


      </LinearGradient>


    </>
  );

}
 

export default DetailsScreen;
```

2nd-screen code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import DropDownItem from "react-native-drop-down-item";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import { SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';


const itm = require('./data/data.json');

const items = [];

items.push(itm);

const AccordianArray = [];

class InfoScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contents: AccordianArray
    };
  }



  render() {

    //const { id, name, SelectType } = this.props.route.params;


    items.map(element => {

      if(SelectType === "bus")
      {
        element.bus.map(busName => {
          busName.Vechiles.map(data => {
  
            if (data.name) {
              AccordianArray.push({
                title: data.name + "    Time: " + data.Time,
                body: data.Des
              }
              )
            }
          })
  
        })


      }
      else if(SelectType === "launch")
      {
        element.launch.map(busName => {
          busName.Vechiles.map(data => {
  
            if (data.name) {
              AccordianArray.push({
                title: data.name + "    Time: " + data.Time,
                body: data.Des
              })
            }
          })
  
        })

      }
      else
      {
        element.train.map(busName => {
          busName.Vechiles.map(data => {
  
            if (data.name) {
              AccordianArray.push({
                title: data.name + "    Time: " + data.Time,
                body: data.Des
              })
            }
          })
  
        })

      }

    });



    return (

      <LinearGradient start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} colors={['#3E7FF5', '#56BEDA', '#6BF4C2']} style={styles.linearGradient}>

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', }}>
            {
              this.state.contents
                ? this.state.contents.map((param, i) => {
                  return (
                    <DropDownItem
                      key={i}
                      style={styles.dropDownItem}
                      contentVisible={false}
                      invisibleImage={require('../img/down-arrow.png')}
                      visibleImage={require('../img/up-arrow.png')}
                      header={
                        <View style={styles.head}>
                          <Text style={{
                            fontSize: 22,

                          }}>{param.title} </Text>
                        </View>
                      }
                    >
                      <Text style={[
                        styles.txt,
                        {
                          fontSize: 20,
                        }
                      ]}>
                        {param.body}
                      </Text>
                    </DropDownItem>
                  );
                })
                : null
            }
            <View style={{ height: 96 }} />


            {/* <Text>{id}</Text>
          <Text>{name}</Text>
          <Text>{SelectType}</Text>        */}

          </ScrollView>
         
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
    ); 

  }

}


export default InfoScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just declare the "const AccordianArray = [];" in side render() function. It will empty your array every time.

Answer (score 0):

Set state equal to Empty Array in the constructor of second.

Comment: can you please tell me in which line i should do it?

Comment: You have to do it to the array which you are using to map over the new data, I'll have to reproduce this first too check line by line.

Comment: I don't understand. I need a solution with code. It is because I tried many times in many different ways but I'm failed.

Comment: Provide data.json file so that I can reproduce,make some dummy data

Comment: here the link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J858I8W2_D3_qFhHC-RO8RgIqofqOl3L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay I'll see it today